# Auto-configuring postfix using dpkg-set-selections

Tags: ubuntu, debian, postfix

On Ubuntu 12.04, I'm trying to use `dpkg-set-selections` to automagically configure postfix on deployed machines with the following:

```
debconf-set-selections <<EOF
postfix postfix/main_mailer_type select Satellite system 
postfix postfix/root_address string admin@mydomain.org
postfix postfix/mailname string mydomain.org
postfix postfix/relayhost string gw.mydomain.internal
postfix postfix/destinations string $(hostname -f), localhost
EOF
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install postfix mailutils
```

Unfortunately, the configurator insists on adding mydomain.org to the `postfix/destinations` (aka `mydestinations`) config parameter:

```
postfix postfix/destinations    string  mydomain.org, myserver.mydomain.internal, localhost
```

How can I configure this properly? I want any unqualified mail to go out as `user@mydomain.org` and be relayed through the smarthost.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the install scripts, `postfix.preinst` has some interesting code about it, and some comments:

> Add a 'mydomain' entry in main.cf for upgrade?  Postfix version
>   2.3.3-2 and later require changes in main.cf.  Specifically, mydomain must be specified, since hostname(1) is not  a fully qualified domain
>   name (FQDN).  .  Failure to fix this will result in a broken mailer.
>   Decline this option  to abort the upgrade, giving you the opportunity
>   to add this configuration  yourself. Accept this option to
>   automatically set mydomain based on the  FQDN of the machine.*